# ...In this way doing

Tags: sentence-construction

> ... The positive charges of these calcium ions in turn alter the
>   electrical state of the channel protein itself, ***in this way
>   altering*** the voltage level required to open the sodium gate. (Guyton and Hall Textbook of Physiology)

Can I rewrite the sentence as in:

> ... The positive charges of these calcium ions in turn alter the
>   electrical state of the channel protein itself, ***altering*** the
>   voltage level required to open the sodium gate ***in this way***.

Comment: The former sounds much better because *in this way* is tied to the part of the sentence before the comma; therefore the delay imposed by interpolating the rest of the sentence would hinder readability, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. Here's my suggestion "... in turn alter the electrical state of the channel protein itself, thus altering the voltage level required to open the sodium gate."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK In fact, newer editions of Guyton's Physiology use that exact phrasing: https://books.google.de/books?id=Po0zyO0BFzwC&pg=PA68&dq=The+positive+charges+of+these+calcium+ions+in+turn+alter+the+electrical+state+of+the+channel+protein+itself,+in+this+way+altering+the+voltage+level+required+to+open+the+sodium+gate.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz_fiL9P_pAhXDyaQKHY_fCdwQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20positive%20charges%20of%20these%20calcium%20ions%20in%20turn%20alter%20the%20electrical%20state%20of%20the%20channel%20protein%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot rewrite the sentence in that way, because an adverb like *in this way* belongs most naturally to the **nearest** verb; your change would move it from *altering* to *open*.